# Alt key is not properly working in JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, keylistener, key-bindings, alt

I am trying to use 'Alt' key to switch between two JTextField in Java. I have used the code:

```
private void GetAltKey(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.isAltDown()) {
            this.GetVectorDirect(true); //Select another JTextField
        }
}
```

Now, this type of code is working, but not properly. I need to press 'Alt' key twice to actually switch over. Not only for that key, it happens for all other keys - the immediately next key press is ignored, i.e., I need to type to press the same key twice.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the first `alt` you are pressing is triggering the GetAltKey event (by the way, consider to change to getAltKey), note please that when this happen your `alt` key isn't down, so your `evt.isAltDown()` is returning false.

The solution is simple, change your `evt.isAltDown()` method to `evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT`.

```
private void getAltKey(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT) {
        this.GetVectorDirect(true); //Select another JTextField
    }
}
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: It worked fine when I used for a single Text field; but when I tried it to switch between 2 Text fields, again 2 key presses are required. Finally, it seems to me that Alt key is serving two works, as it is guided by the program and the other one is default behavior in windows- selecting Menu options. So, I decided to use Pgup and Pgdn keys instead. And it is working properly.

Comment: You can try the following, put a System.out.println("Alt pressed") before the this.GetVectorDirect(true) and you will see that the program is getting it everytime you press your alt key

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, key listeners tend to be troublesome and generally generate a lot of messing `if-else` statements.

```
public class KeyBindingsTransfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyBindingsTransfer();
    }

    public KeyBindingsTransfer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TransferPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class TransferPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea left;
        private JTextArea right;

        public TransferPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 4, 4));

            left = new JTextArea();
            right = new JTextArea();

            add(left);
            add(right);

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 0, true), "transferOnAlt");

            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
            actionMap.put("transferOnAlt", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                    if (left.hasFocus()) {
                        right.requestFocusInWindow();
                    } else if (right.hasFocus()) {
                        left.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```